# Need ability to allow users to securely embed javascript in their profile

Tags: javascript, xss

I am building a web app & I want to allow users the ability to embed javascript on their personal profile page. Now, I know this opens huge security issues (xss & man in the middle attacks). I want to allow this functionality, but I want to do it securely. Can anyone point me to some condensed information on how to accomplish this? I've done some Google searches but its all over the board.

Comment: Look what Stackoverflow does with the snipplets...

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost you must embed everything inside a iframe. Best would be on a sub-domain (or even better a different domain) so it can't get access to the same origin (where you store users cookies and other client side storage)
however you can get await with using the same origin (domain) if you ensure you use sandboxed attributes correctly and if you know if it's supported

Set your cookies to http-only so javascript can't get access to them...

Second i suggest you read more about the [sandboxed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#attr-sandbox) attribute to limit what the script can and can't do

To top it all of also take a look at [content security policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP) to limit what can and can't be done (it's more like black/whitelisting things)

Comment: It is better to use a completely different domain. With sub-domain you can still set `document.domain` to release the restriction of same origin policy

Comment: Does using an iframe completely mitigate the potential for xss attacks? If that is so, I will completely disallow JS all together. Sorry if this is a dumb question.

Comment: Cookies are good :) Symfony defaults all cookies to HttpOnly.

Comment: No. iframe's don't solve xss attacks on same domain. Sandbox attribute however can fix xss attacks